# jQuery UI Buttonset Not Adding Classes To Child Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm having an (intermittent) issue with jQuery UI's buttonset function. Sometimes when I call it, it only applies the classes it adds to the container div and the first child, and other times it works exactly as expected. (Sorry, I can't make a fiddle for this, I can't get it to happen outside of my application.) Same issue with both jQuery UI 1.10.0 and 1.10.4.

i.e. I start with this:

```
<div class="my-buttonset">
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="option1">
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="option" id="option2">
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label>

    <!-- More elements -->
</div>
```

and get this after calling buttonset (note the radio button does get a single, incorrect class added):

```
<div class="my-buttonset ui-buttonset">
    <input class="ui-corner-left" type="radio" name="option" id="option1">
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="option" id="option2">
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label>

    <!-- Other elements unchanged -->
</div>
```

instead of this:

```
<div class="container-fluid-full radio-row mode-radio-row ui-buttonset">
    <input class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="radio" name="option" id="option1">
    <label class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-state-hover" for="option1" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Option 1</span></label>

    <input class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="radio" name="option" id="option2">
    <label class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-state-hover" for="option2" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Option 2</span></label>

    <!-- Other elements correct -->
</div>
```

Update: I can reproduce this consistently in my application. The application uses AngularJS, and I have 2 views that make use of the button set, call them "A" and "B". It always happens if I go to "A", refresh the page, then navigate to "B". It never happens in the reverse order, or if I start from any other view in the application. Previously, it would not happen if I recreated it then navigated back to "A", but now that I refactored it into a directive, if I refresh at "A", I see the correct button set, go to "B", I see the messed up version, then navigate to "A" and I see the messed up one there too, and it also effects a second button set on "A" that is not part of the directive.

I tried recreating a basic example in JS Fiddle, with two views utilizing buttonset, but it wasn't enough to recreate the bug.

Comment: As per your description I guess the classes loads fine on the pageload and when you navigate to another page classes gets messedup then it means it is having a problem in referencing the CSS. Make sure the  CSS is refered globally.

Comment: @Dexture I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Regardless of whether or not the CSS itself is available to the page, it should have nothing to do with JavaScript code adding the wrong classes. If it were adding the correct classes and not getting styled that would be an entirely different issue. (Also, all our CSS is compiled into one file, and included as part of the container page, which loads the views. tl;dr all pages have all the CSS rules.)

Comment: Maybe you call buttonset before all DOM elements are ready? I never tried angular and don't know how it works, but in ember for example it is possible and there are special methods where you should make jquery calls.

Comment: So where is this button HTML defined? In angular view or directive? And where's the function call that does all the transformation? Are these options generated by ng-repeat? Because what could happen is that the jQuery ui call fires before the DOM elements are rendered by AngularJS - so this is the point @GennadyDogaev is making.

Comment: I believe it was in a directive. Unfortunately at this point I no longer have access to the code in question (I've changed jobs since this was asked), and I don't know of any public deployments of the application I could check, so anything else is just guessing at this point.

Comment: I had posted an aswer with a directive, but I suspect you has a directive. Try to find some jquery-ui event based on your classes... or, try to eliminate all classes, and then, insert one by one back, to find what class is interfering your code

Comment: The "I can't get it to happen outside of my application" tells me it is something else on the page that is having an impact here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've broken my head with this exactly same issue for about a day without finding a solution.

The problem, in my case, were the use of Bootstrap.

Bootstrap also manages buttons and it uses the same name `buttons`as used by Jquery UI.

The solution (really really as simple as non findable!!!) were to simply change the order of inclusion on the page: `Bootstrap.js` first and then `jquery-ui...js`.

This simple thing solved the issue (also if it remains the conflict).

For a more solid solution, maybe useful to use [JQuery UI Bridge](https://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget.bridge/) or to [put Bootstrap in no conflict mode](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-noconflict) (but I haven't tested these solutions at the moment, also if I'm 99% sure they will solve the problem).

NOTE: The same conflict exsists also for tooltips.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say for sure since I can't check, but we were using both of those, and the different navigation orders may have lead to different load orders since the JS was loaded asynchronously. I'm going to accept this because it seems very plausible.

Answer (score 3):

The best option for you is to make a directive out of your jQuery UI buttonset component. It is very likely that your component loads well when its UI element is viisble and fails when it's not.

Another option is to call the jQuery init function as soon as a new view is loaded, that way you make sure that the buttonset is visible when you try to initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

try to make a directive, for post angular link with your page (sample on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jicuruwepu/edit?html,js,output))

directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('jsButtonset', function() {
    return function(scope, el, attrs) {
        el.buttonset();
    };
});
```

and use the directive at button container:

```
<div js-buttonset>
```